# "No such file" error when directing output to a file

Tags: command-line, files

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. In my accounts `.bashrc` file I have the line

```
alias ftreport='cd / && sudo tree > /home/<user name here>/Documents/Reports/Tree_$(date +%s).txt'
```

After typing the command `ftreport`, I get

```
bash: /home/<user name here>/Documents/Reports/Tree_<epoc time here>.txt: No such file or directory
```

The command `ftreport` must output my system's file tree in my ~/Documents/Reports folder with the file title consisting of "File", an underscore, the epoch time, and ".txt". What is wrong and what should it be?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you change `<user name here>` to your username. And make sure that you can write in the `~/Documents/Reports` folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
alias tpsreport='cd / && mkdir -p /home/$(whoami)/Documents/Reports && sudo tree > /home/$(whoami)/Documents/Reports/TPS_$(date +%s).txt && cd -'
```

Seems to work...